# OWIN based WS-Federation metadata endpoint for relying party application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, ws-federation

I have an application setup with the Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation package and using ADFS as the identity provider.

I have setup my application as a relying party in ADFS by entering urls and claims manually, but would like to ease the process for future deployments of the application.

Is there something built into OWIN to expose metadata for my application (the RP) for the ADFS to consume? Or do I have to construct the metadata output outside of OWIN?